# Android Services

Tags: android, service

What are the disadvantages of running services in Android in Foreground.??
  I recently read that if you want your services to last longer and not get killed easily we need to run the service in foreground.

Comment: I guess services are used to run in background instead of foreground and it can not be helpful at all if you run it in foreground as it is the same mechanism that is provided by single thread of control running on UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

What you read is right. It depends on what you want to do with your application. If your service does something which should not be interrupted without explicit user-interaction you should start it as a foreground-service. This assures that the service won't get killed if more memory is needed by other applications. Also you have an ongoing notification displayed so that the user is aware of what is happening and you can provide functionality to your notification such as opening an activity when tapping on the notification etc. Examples for this may be a music player service or a download service. If you have a service which does not have to run necessarily after leaving the app you should choose a service started in background, so that the memory can be released if it is needed for other tasks. Some more information you can find here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html